# Angular keeps redirecting me to the login page even though I'm trying to access another page

Tags: html, angular, ngx-admin

I have a website that it is divided into a normal pages that can be accessed by the user and another page that it is only accessible by admins(which is the [ngx-admin](https://akveo.com/ngx-admin/pages/dashboard)).

So to block users from being able to access the admin dashboard I have setup an auth guard which redirect the user to the login page and if they have the wrong credentials it'll redirect them to the home page of the website but for some reason whenever I try to access the home page or anything else I always get redirected the login page.

Here's my app-routing module:

```
import { ExtraOptions, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {
NbAuthComponent,
NbLoginComponent,
NbLogoutComponent,
NbRegisterComponent,
NbRequestPasswordComponent,
NbResetPasswordComponent,
} from '@nebular/auth';
import { AuthGuard } from './auth-guard.service';
import { HomeComponent } from './Home/home.component';
import { OffreAComponent } from './offrea/offrea.component';
const routes: Routes = [
{path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
{path: 'offreappel', component: OffreAComponent},
{ path: 'users', loadChildren: 'app/pages/pages.module#PagesModule', canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
{
path: 'auth',
component: NbAuthComponent,
children: [
  {
    path: '',
    component: NbLoginComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: NbLoginComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'register',
    component: NbRegisterComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'logout',
    component: NbLogoutComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'request-password',
    component: NbRequestPasswordComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'reset-password',
    component: NbResetPasswordComponent,
  },
],
 },
{ path: '**', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'users'},
];
const config: ExtraOptions = {
useHash: true,
};

 @NgModule({
 imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, config)],
 exports: [RouterModule],
 })
 export class AppRoutingModule {
 }
```

And here's my AuthGuard service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { NbAuthService } from '@nebular/auth';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
constructor(private authService: NbAuthService, private router: Router) {}

canActivate() {
return this.authService.isAuthenticated().pipe(
    tap(authenticated => {
        if (!authenticated) {
            this.router.navigate(['auth/login']);
        }
    }),
);
}}
```

Comment: Is the route `/home`  having problems too?

Comment: Whenever I try to access '/home' or 'offreappel' I get redirected to the login page

Comment: How does your url look like? `localhost:4200/home`?

Comment: When i type 'localhost:4200/home' it changes to 'http://localhost:4200/home#/auth/login' and when i login it becomes 'http://localhost:4200/home#/home'

Comment: You are using the hash with `useHash: true`. Your url should be localhost:4200/#/home . It's working as expected then.

Comment: Yep, there's your issue, there's no route to be found and it routes to your wild card route `path: '**'` which prompted the login because it tries to go to `users` but has `AuthGuard`

Comment: @penleychan so what should i do?

Comment: I'd recommend not use hash, unless you have a reason to use it?

Comment: You have a lot of options. I usually redirect to the home page when there is an error of routing.

Comment: @penleychan when i tried removing the 'use hash' and typed 'localhost:4200/home' I get a loading screen that gets stuck and doesn't show anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a **redirect** to `users` on error of the routing.

```
   { path: '**', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'users'},
```

So every time you go to a **wrong path** it would **redirect** to:

```
{ path: 'users', loadChildren: 'app/pages/pages.module#PagesModule', canActivate: [AuthGuard]}
```

I would consider adding a page with route as default and when a route does not match redirect to that page:

```
{ path: '', component: HomeComponent},
{ path: '**', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: ''},
```

Another thing to note check if you really need the `useHash`. This is necesary for some environments only.

Comment: Thank you so much, It's working but i'm getting another issue. When I try to access 'localhost:4200/home' the page keeps loading forever. Why is that?

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.
For the loadind forever you should post another question and add your code in www.stackblitz.com so We can help you better.